# Проблема преобразования типов в generic методах

Tags: c#

Есть следующий пример (переписан для упрощения понимания):

```
public class Programm
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var warehouse = new Warehouse_var1<int>();
        warehouse.AddBoxFruit<Apple>(new AppleBox());
    }
}

public class Warehouse_var1<TAmount>
{
    private List<BoxFruit<Fruit<TAmount>>> list = new List<BoxFruit<Fruit<TAmount>>>();

    public void AddBoxFruit<TFruit>(BoxFruit<TFruit> boxFruit)
        where TFruit : Fruit<TAmount>
    {
        MyGenericMethod<TFruit>();

        list.Add(boxFruit);
    }

    private void MyGenericMethod<TFruit>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic Method!");
    }
}

//Модель фрукта, количество которого измеряется в TAmount
public class Fruit<TAmount> { }
//Реализация фрукта - Яблоко
public class Apple : Fruit<int> { }
//Реализация фрукта - Груша
public class Pear : Fruit<long> { }

//Имеется коробка, для хранения фруктов
public class BoxFruit<TFruit> { }
//Коробка с яблоками
public class AppleBox : BoxFruit<Apple> { }
//Коробка с грушами
public class PearBox : BoxFruit<Pear> { }
```

1. Имеются фрукты, для которых можно указать, в чем измеряется их
   количество TAmount.
2. Есть коробки, которые хранят определенные
   фрукты TFruit.
3. И есть главный класс Warehouse, который хранит
   коробки с фруктами, но только с определенным типом измерения их
   количества TAmount.

Склад(Warehouse) должен уметь добавлять к себе коробки с фруктами только с конкретным указанным TAmount у Фрукта. Для этого реализован метод AddBoxFruit. Он является generic, т.к. в нем используется MyGenericMethod, который на основании переданного типа, будет совершать какие-либо действия, **от данного метода отказаться нельзя, он необходим для правильной работы программы.** После его выполнения - элемент добавляется в список.

Компилятор выкидывает следующие ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит, если у метода установлено ограничение
`where TFruit : Fruit<TAmount>` т.е. точно такое же, как и в списке ?

Каким-то образом нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было добавлять в коллекцию любые коробки с фруктами, при этом, чтобы обязательно срабатывал GenericMethod на основании типа переданного фрукта.

Comment: Обобщения предназначены чтобы у объектов определить что-то общее, за счет чего работать с ними а коллекциях без приведения к базовому типу. В приведенном примере кроме ваших слов типа "не спрашивайте зачем, просто так надо", нет ни одной причины поддерживать структуру на этом уровне сложости. Классы пустые. Упростите пример, но приведите к рабочему состояию, где понятно что для чего. `TAmount` это просто одно и то же что и `T`, просто другими буквами написано, и сбивает с толку. Давайте от абстракции к конкретике с обозначеием проблемы. А пока решение - просто выбросить половину кода.

Comment: [Wizards and warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/). Давно читал, толком не помню... Помню лишь, что проникся и перестал мудрить со сложными дженериками. YAGNI и KISS - наше фсё!